# Running multiple t tests through looping columns in R

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics

For this exercise I will look at the dataset, `iris`.  What I want to do is to run the t-test between the first column and columns 2, 3, and 4.  so in the end we have 4 results, `t.test(c1, c2)`, `t.test (c1, c3)`, `t.test(c1, c4)`, `t.test(c1, c5)`.  Here's what I have so far. I'm getting some values but I'm not sure if its the right ones.

```
result <- vector("list", 4)
for (i in 1:4) {
    x = iris[ , 1]
    y = iris[ , i + 1]
    result[i] = t.test(x, y)$p.value
}
```

Comment: What do you think you should have as correct output? You need to determine this before you begin writing the code, or you will bang your head dreadfully against many, many walls.

Comment: I want to have the p value.  I'm not sure if those are the right ones though.  Are they?

Comment: how about testing your results independently. `t.test(iris[,1],iris[,2])$p.value
[1] 1.459543e-96`

Comment: Programmatically I don't see anything wrong in your code. If you are asking about statistics, you should probably adjust the p-values for multiple testing.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

iris %>%
  select(-Species) %>%
  gather(variable, value, -Sepal.Length) %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  summarize(p = t.test(Sepal.Length, value)$p.value)
```

Comment: This is fine code, but doesn't address the OP question that is asking how to validate or have confidence in the result, not how to improve code.